# How to install ArmCord 3.0.8 on Kubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, 22.04

I want to install ArmCord, however the Snap Store version is broken, so I can't use that.
I see that they have a bunch of different packages available on their [README page](https://github.com/ArmCord/ArmCord/blob/dev/README.md),
but I don't know what the differences are or what's compatible with my distro.

I'm also not very familiar with the terminal yet, so I'd appreciate an explanation of what each command necessary for the install does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the latest compiled binary from Sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/armcord/files/latest/download

Then, right click and extract the archive.

Afterwards, run the file named `armcord`.

Comment: That was... surprisingly easy.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [ArmCord's GitHub page](https://github.com/ArmCord/ArmCord):

> ## How to run/install it?
>
> ---
>
> ### Recommended:
>
> Check releases tab for precompiled packages for Linux, Windows and Mac OS. Alternatively use our Sourceforge mirror.

So you can either download a precompiled binary from Sourceforge, as [Archisman Panigrahi already mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/1436929/618353), or you can go to the [*Releases*](https://github.com/ArmCord/ArmCord/releases) section of the project, click *Assets* on the latest version (3.0.8 currently) and select `ArmCord_3.0.8_amd64.deb` (click [here](https://github.com/ArmCord/ArmCord/releases/download/v3.0.8/ArmCord_3.0.8_amd64.deb) to directly download it).

After downloading the `ArmCord_3.0.8_amd64.deb` file, run the following command to install it:

```
sudo apt install /path/to/ArmCord_3.0.8_amd64.deb
```

In the above command you need to replace `/path/to/ArmCord_3.0.8_amd64.deb` with the correct path to your downloaded `.deb` file (e.g. `/home/user/Downloads/ArmCord_3.0.8_amd64.deb` if you downloaded it to your `Downloads` directory and your username is `user`).

You can then launch ArmCord either from your applications menu or by opening a terminal and running:

```
armcord
```

**Note:** Since you are confused about the packages in Ubuntu, I should mention that Ubuntu uses the `.deb` package format, that's why the above instructions tell you how to download and install the `.deb` package.

Comment: I did not notice the .deb package. Nice :)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yeah, it's somewhat hidden in the list. ;)